# Parallel A* search in C# - different paths

Tags: parallel-processing, path-finding, a-star, bidirectional

I'm working on some bidirectional A* algorithm. I'm searching from end to start, and from start to end. When the first thread encounters with a node from other thread(from open or closed list) it stops and draws a path back.

But I have the problem when the thread take different paths and they dont meet where they should.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hsCA.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a common problem that discouraged research of bidirectional search until Kaindl & Kainz proved it unnecessary in 1997. Section 2.3 of [PNBA*: A Parallel Bidirectional Heuristic Search Algorithm](http://www.dimap.ufrn.br/csbc2011/anais/eventos/contents/ENIA/ENIA_Sessao_6_Artigo_1_Rios.pdf) provides additional historical background, as well as a (parallel) bidirectional algorithm that overcomes this issue.

You may wish to read [Yet Another Bidirectional Algorithm for Shortest Paths](http://repub.eur.nl/res/pub/16100/ei2009-10.pdf) first as the (serial)  **NBA*** algorithm it describes is referenced by the first paper extensively.

I have just successfully adapted my open source Hexgrid PathFinding utility found [here](http://hexgridutilities.codeplex.com/) to use a serial version of PNBA*. (Really about half-way between NBA* and PNBA*) This will be uploaded within a day or two.

[Making the Shortest Path Even Quicker](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/news/features/shortestpath-070709.aspx) gives an overview of developing the Bing Maps path finder using Bidirectional A* with pre-processing. A detailed description of the preprocessing work, and use of the relevant algorithm, is available in [Reach for A*](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=60764) and [Better Landmarks Within Reach](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64505)